# How to test statements individually rather than a block of code using Try-Catch?

Tags: c#, try-catch, try-catch-finally

The code below will fail because Bind() is called on a socket that has not been "prepared", even though there is code to prepare the socket. The code that prepares the socket is out of scope (another Try block).

```
        // prepare socket
        try
        {
            socket = new Socket(endPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.write("socket preparation failed");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (socket != null)
            {
                socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                socket.Close();
            }
        }

        // bind
        try
        {
            socket.Bind(endPoint);
        }   
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.write("Bind() failed");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (socket != null)
            {
                socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                socket.Close();
            }
        }

        // enable listening
        try
        {
            socket.Listen(1000);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.write("Listen() failed");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (socket != null)
            {
                socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                socket.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Put it into separate methods.

Comment: Instead of defacing your own post, either accept an answer, post your own answer (and accept it), or flag your question for moderator deletion.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to write it.  The `finally` is part of an outer scope, while all your `catches` are in inner scope.  I'm `throwing` after each `catch`, but you can handle it differently.

Note that each `finally` clause is executed as soon as it's corresponding `try` clause falls out of scope, not when the method exists.

```
    Socket socket;

    try
    {
        // prepare socket
        try
        {
            socket = new Socket(endPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        }
        catch
        {
            log.write("socket preparation failed");
            throw;
        }

        // bind
        try
        {
            socket.Bind(endPoint);
        }   
        catch
        {
            log.write("Bind() failed");
            throw;
        }

        // enable listening
        try
        {
            socket.Listen(1000);
        }
        catch
        {
            log.write("Listen() failed");
            throw;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (socket != null)
        {
            socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            socket.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the exceptions are always being treated the same way, why don't you try this way...

```
string message = string.Empty;

try
{
    message = "socket preparation failed";
    socket = new Socket(endPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    message = "Bind() failed";
    socket.Bind(endPoint);

    message = "Listen() failed";
    socket.Listen(1000);

    message = string.Empty;
}
catch
{
    log.write(message);
}
finally
{
    if (socket != null)
    {
        socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        socket.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, I like to use custom wrapper classes, I find them to be a bit neater and have a bit more ability to customize to your needs (especially when it comes to throwing errors in a neater fashion)

So you could write a class that implements `Socket`, we'll call it `CustomSocket`

```
public class CustomSocket : Socket {

    private EndPoint endPoint;

    public CustomSocket(EndPoint endPoint, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType)
        : base(endPoint.AddressFamily, socketType, protocolType) {
            this.endPoint = endPoint;
    }

    public virtual void Bind() {
        try {
            base.Bind(endPoint);
        } catch {
            // do logging here
            throw new Exception("Bind() failed");
        }
    }

    public virtual void Listen(int backlog) {
        try {
            base.Listen(backlog);
        } catch {
            // do logging here
            throw new Exception("Listen() failed");
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

And then you could implement it like so:

```
        using (CustomSocket socket = new CustomSocket(new IPEndPoint(new IPAddress(new byte[1]), 5000), SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)) {
            try {
                socket.Bind();
                socket.Listen(1000);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // do stuff with ex here
            }
        }
```

Also, implementing the `using` method of doing this will make it so you don't have to manually call `Close()` and/or `Shutdown()`. (`using` automatically calls `Dispose()` when it reaches the end, and `Dispose()` is the same thing as `Close()`. When `Close()` is called, if you haven't already explicitly initiated a `Shutdown()` it will initiate it for you)